# C++ Binary Stream

Tags: c++, file, io, binary

I must be missing something simple here, but I am trying to write and read a binary file in C++.

```
    ofstream file3("C:\\data2.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    file3.write((char*)(&i), sizeof(int));
}

ifstream file4("C:\\data2.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

int temp;
while (!file4.eof()) {
    file4.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(int));
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

The file looks like it is getting created properly when viewed with a hex editor. However, as I go to read the file it reads 1 random junk value and quits vs. listing out all the numbers.

### Update

I made a slight update based on the comments and all seems good now. On Windows the close made a difference and I did fix the loop condition.

```
    ofstream file3("C:\\data2.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    file3.write((char*)(&i), sizeof(int));
}

file3.close();
ifstream file4("C:\\data2.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

//cout << file4.eof();
int temp;
while (!file4.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(int)).eof()) {
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong Also you need to close the file before you open it again for reading

Comment: Usually the ".txt" extension is reserved for human readable content.

Comment: You could open the file as `fstream`, flush after writing, then rewind (or reposition the file pointer to the beginning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have permission to write to `c:\\file`, so you should check if you can. As for using `.eof()` see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Finally, you might want to close the file before you open it again for reading. Here is your example tweaked:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file3("data2.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if (file3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            file3.write((char*)(&i), sizeof(int));
        }
        file3.close();
    }

    std::ifstream file4("data2.txt", std::ios::binary);

    int temp;
    while (file4)
    {
        file4.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(int));
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8f519fcd05879855

Comment: Yep the close made a difference. I am coming from C and will while(file4) work. Does the file descriptor become 0 once eof is hit in c++?

Comment: @ArnabC. I think [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) should answer your question why file4 becomes false at the end of read